# Websockets: Data Design Patterns

Tags: api, design-patterns, websocket

I'm looking for some help with best practices and standards for my first Websockets chat app. I don't have any reference for this– so this is what I have currently implemented. There are many types of Messages that can be sent in this service:

```
• Text Messages
• Video Messages
• Image Messages
... etc
```

So imagine chatrooms that multiple people can be in.
Here is how I am thinking about sending messages from the **client to server**:

```
{
  "type": "room.message",
  "data": {
    "meta": {
      "color": "#FFFFFF"
    },
    "message": "Hello, how are you?"
  }
}
```

This is the design for the message being sent down from the **server to the clients** connected to the room.

```
{
  "type": "room.message_broadcast",
  "data": {
    "meta": {
      "color": "#FFFFFF"
    },
    "message": "Hello, how are you?",
    "user": userObject
  }
}
```

From a best practices standpoint, does it make sense to follow this `type` and `type_broadcast` format? Following on from that, does it make sense how I'm structuring the interior data structure regarding `type` and `data`? Following this same pattern, we would do this for images:

```
{
  "type": "room.image",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://www.google.com/someimage.png"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "type": "room.image_broadcast",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://www.google.com/someimage.png"
    "user": userObject
  }
}
```

From a design perspective, does this pattern make sense for a realtime chat room with multiple types?